# CSS ,Responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

Let's say I have the following mark-up:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .floatleft {
        float: left;
     }

    .floatright {
        float: right;
     }
</style>

<div id="container">
      <div id="box1" class="floatleft"></div>
      <div id="box2" class="floatright"></div>   
</div>
```

When I view this on a small screen on an iPad or iPhone *etc*. The two boxes will either:

- Shrink (but stay next to each other) *or*
- `#box2` will "*jump*" down and position itself under `#box1`.

**Q**: How do I make `#box2` jump down under the first `<div />`?

Comment: First, your `div`s aren't closed correctly. You should also post your CSS. But really, you need to set `@media` queries for the small screens and adjust your css accordingly.

Comment: Can you clarify, in your last sentence you say box2 will jump under box2. Do you mean box1 will jump under box2?

Comment: @user2915962 but I made a mistake on the class name, should be `.floatright` for the second `<div>`, *big* apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) and remove the floating on small sized screens.

Answer (score 1):

Change `#box2` to `float: left;` when on a mobile device, using a media query.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to remove the property `float` with mediaqueries:

```
@media screen and (max-width:480px) {
   #box1, #box2 {
     float:none;
   }
}
```

The demo **http://jsfiddle.net/yYq8W/8/**